# Make custom label control resize

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, custom-controls, label

I have a custom control label that I am trying to give all the same properties and functionality to as a regular label. I can change the text, font, and assign the auto size property. However, I cannot figure out a way to make the control re-size correctly. Does anyone have any suggestions or code examples of a custom control being re-sized to fill the entire control? Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: "a custom control being resized to fill the entire control" doesn't make sense.  Use the source code available for the Label control to see how it does it.  Available here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx, dd/ndp/fx/src/winforms/managed/system/winforms/label.cs

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail (possibly with code samples) of what you have done so far and what happens now when you try to resize and what you expect it to do instead?

Comment: At the moment, resizing the control does nothing to control. I am expecting the Text that is inside the control to expand to the fill the entire length of the control. Basically when dragging the control around, I want the text in the label to change in size with the control.

Comment: And its a Windows Form Application.

Comment: dont use "vb.net" or "c#" in your titles.  That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick custom component which inherits Label which will do this :

```
Partial Class MyLabel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label

    Private _fWidth As Integer
    Private _fHeight As Integer
    Private _fSize As Single
    Private _fFix As Boolean = False

    Public Property Fix() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _fFix
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _fFix = value
            If _fFix Then
                _fWidth = Me.Width
                _fHeight = Me.Height
                _fSize = Me.Font.Size
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnResize(e)
        If _fFix Then
            Dim nStyle As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular _
                                 + CInt(Me.Font.Bold) * FontStyle.Bold _
                                 + CInt(Me.Font.Italic) * FontStyle.Italic _
                                 + CInt(Me.Font.Underline) * FontStyle.Underline _
                                 + CInt(Me.Font.Strikeout) * FontStyle.Strikeout
            Dim nFont As New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, _
                          _fSize * Me.Width / _fWidth, _
                           nStyle, GraphicsUnit.Point)
            Me.Font = nFont
            Me.Height = _fHeight * (Me.Width / _fWidth)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

To make this work you have to set `AutoSize = False` and the new Property `Fix = true`.  Then when the label is resized it will scale the font appropriately.  This is a very fast implementation.  There are obvously a lot of places to extend this to make it more intelligent but hopefully this should give you a start and some ideas.